# Is it possible to create multiple objects from an XML file?

Tags: c#

```
public class xmlvalues
{
    public int    id { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}

-- XML Example
<instance>
  <id>>1</id>
  <a>value 1A</a>
  <b>value 1B</b>
  <c>value 1C</c>
</instance>


<instance>
  <id>>2</id>
  <a>value 2A</a>
  <b>value 2B</b>
  <c>value 2C</c>
</instance>
```

Using the above example is possible to create an object for each "instance" node in the XML file?  In this example there would be 2 instances of the object "xmlvalues" but in theory there could be many more. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Use List<xmlvalues> + XML serialization

Comment: U could use a simple `loop` and `LINQ to XML` to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using list

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"...\path\document.xml");

List<xmlvalues> lists = (from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("instance")
                       select new xmlvalues
                       {
                           id = lv1.Element("id"),
                           a= lv1.Element("a"),
                           b= lv1.Element("b"),
                           c= lv1.Element("c")
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: A minor correction: `lvl.Attribute` should be `lvl.GetElement()`. Otherwise, this answer is a winner.

Comment: @MikeHofer Thanx,  it would be lvl.GetElement() instead of lvl.Attribute

Comment: Saw that, and already corrected the comment. :) Still gave you the up vote.

Comment: Edited.. have a check

Comment: Thanks.  I've given this a try but I get an exception while it's running say that there are multiple root elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, you would have to adapt your xpath:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

foreach  (XElement el  in xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElements ( "instance" ) ) { 
     //do something with el
}
```

This is faster than .Descendants() because it doesn't have to check all the nodes, just the ones found at the x-path ("instance" in the above case)